# What is impact of document archival because of time to live on the physical partition in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Does physical partition get reclaimed once it becomes empty when all documents in that partition are archived because of Time to Live has been elapsed.

Comment: If I understand correctly, once the TTL on a document is expired it gets deleted permanently and not archived.

Comment: How would you know when a physical partition is empty? You only manage logical partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Cosmos DB TTL document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/time-to-live): When you configure TTL, the system will automatically delete the expired items based on the TTL value, without needing a delete operation that is explicitly issued by the client application,which means the items are deleted with TTL.

And you only can manage logical partitions. Azure Cosmos DB automatically manages the placement of logical partitions on physical partitions. The explanation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#managing-logical-partitions):

Azure Cosmos DB hashes the partition key value of an item. The hashed result determines the physical partition. Then, Azure Cosmos DB allocates the key space of partition key hashes evenly across the physical partitions,which means when you remove all documents in one partition,cosmos db will allocate the physical partitions automatically.You could just  need to care about your construction on logical partition.

Comment: Let me ask question other way round, as we know  - the RUs allocated per partition (physical) is  = total RUs / total partition count and one logical partition would not extend to multiple physical partition. which means if I am writing to a logical partition it would have budget of allocated RUs for that partition.

Comment: Another aspect is  -  what is constant in context of Physical partition - Size of partition , Number of partition. There is important aspect of RUs getting spread across physical partition. In my case I have > 50 partition, with RUs configured as 15K. At the end each physical partition gets very less RUs. Do we know what could be the reason for such high number of physical partition

Comment: It does not get reclaimed. Once provisioned the physical partitions backing your logical partitions and storage remain dedicated to your account. The reason is because this allows Cosmos to scale back up instantly as the first large scale up can take some time to complete. As a result the minimum possible throughput after a large scale up is ~10% the max throughput ever provisioned.